# index server and statistics server not starting in HANA

Tags: hana

In SAP HANA index server and statistics server stopped suddenly and not running.

I tried to stop and restart the server by the following commands.

```
 HDB stop 
 HDB start
```

But still it is not working. Does anyone know what causes this problem and what is the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the HDB start show any errors?

Comment: No It does not show any error.But the if I login to the SYSTEM it shows that statistics server and index server is stopped and not running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the indexserver doesn't start, you cannot logon as SYSTEM (or any other user for that matter). A good way to find out what the reason for the failed start is to check the tracefile for the nameserver, the indexserver and the statisticsserver.

Logon as `<sid>adm` and change to the tracefile folder via `cdtrace`.
Then find the tracefiles and use e.g. `less` to read through them to find the actual error messages.

Alternatively you can use SAP HANA Studio with the emergency connection to review the trace files without terminal access.